# meteor: identify client and send data to this specific client - creating block-element on other clients

Tags: javascript, mongodb, session, meteor, temporary

My meteor app has to be used on multiple PCs by the same user, but I have to prevent a simultanous usage of the app at the same time. The problem is, that the user will change the workplace on a high frequence, so it is not a great idea to login and logout each time the user is changing the PC. I thought of using a temporary logout / blocking screen:

Example: There are five PCs. The user has been logged in the app on all five PCs. Now he wants to work on PC 1: On all other four PCs the app will be temporarily blocked by displaying an transparent overlay. If he is going to PC 2 he can remove the overlay by typing a small PIN (which is faster then doing a complete login), then he can work on this PC.

PC 1 will be blocked at the same time.

The overlay could look like this:

```
<div id="overlay" class="{{tempLogout}}">
    <input type="text" id="pin">
</div>

#overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

#overlay.logout {
    display: block !important;
}
```

In my helper I would do this:

```
Template.anything.helper({
    tempLogout: function() {
        return (Session.get('currentClient') == clientID) ? '' : 'logout';
    }
});
```

Now the overlay will be shown if the Session variable is `false`.

My problem is how to let the different clients know on which the user is currently working. And this information has to be reactive.

So in my concept I would create a random ID for each PC (maybe there is already existing any option to identify each client??) and save this ID to an data-attribute on the body-element:

```
$('body').attr('data-id', Random.id());
```

By typing the correct PIN, this ID will be saved to the user-collection:

```
var clientID = $('body').attr('data-id');
Session.set('currentClient', clientID);
Users.update({ _id: Meteor.id() }, { $set: { 'currentClient': clientID } });
```

By setting the Session variable to the new client ID, all other clients will get blocked, as the Session variable is reactive. Here I don't know which storage I have to use: the Session or the Collection.

Maybe someone has a smarter idea to get this done. Especially I think storing the clientID in a data-attribute is a little bit... hacky??
And how do I get the client ID into the helper - because there has to be the check if the currentClient is the same, then the clientID...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your concept should work.
You should use Meteor.user() so you don't have to subscribe to anything (in your example you use a generic collection Users).

You should use a global clientID and avoid to insert it in html.
Something like:

```
  //on client
    clientID = Random.id(); //in Meteor a variable without var is global


Template.anything.helper({
    tempLogout: function() {
        return Meteor.user().profile.clientID == clientID ? '' : 'logout';
    }
});
```

When the correct pin is inserted:

```
   Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {'profile.clientID':clientID}});
```

You have to use Session or a global template helper if you have more than a template which you want to enable/disable.

Comment: And `clientID = Random.id();` will be fixed for one client as it changes just on a reload?

Comment: Anytime you reload app it will change but I don't think it's a problem. Everytime somebody login you will display the pin form. I think the only solution it's try, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be very difficult without making use of Meteor.logoutOtherClients() (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_logoutotherclients). If you used something like oauth for your login mechanism, the login piece would be a simple button click to get back into the application, which is actually a lot simpler than a pin.

Comment: I don't know anything of `oauth`. Could you give me some more infos to that?

Comment: It's very simple. Just add the accounts-google or accounts-facebook package and set up the oauth credentials with google developer console or facebook developer. It lets a user log in to your app with their google or facebook account with a single click.

https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/roll-your-own-authentication/

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not an option for this app.